# What is a good way to store static data? Like items and their stats, rewarddata or waypoints on a map for a towerdefense game

Tags: kotlin

Here is how I'm currently storing/calling the rewarddata:

```
class Map(context: Context, screenX: Int, screenY: Int) {

    
    var level = 0
    var stage = 0
    val screenWidth = screenX
    val screenHeight = screenY
    var xpReward = 0f
    var goldReward = 0f


    fun getRewardData(Level: Int = level, Stage: Int = stage): Array<Float> {
        when (Level) {
            0 -> {
                when (Stage) {
                    0 -> {
                        goldReward = 50f
                        xpReward = 15f
                    }
                    1 -> {

                    }
                    2 -> {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return arrayOf(xpReward, goldReward)
    }
}
```

Then in a different class I'm calling for the data so I can display it:

```
val rewards = map.getRewardData(chosenLevel, levelSelectScreen.stage)
```

It all just feels inefficient/amateuristic or at least like there should be a better way to do this.

Comment: How often is this information likely to change?  If you're likely to be making occasional tweaks or additions, then a resource file is often a good approach; if you'll be making frequent changes, then maybe it would be better stored (as a file or in a DB) on a server somewhere.  But if you don't expect it to change much, or at all, then it can be simpler to declare it in the code.

Comment: When you say "declare it in the code" do you mean how I'm already doing it? Or like in Max Farsikov's answer?

Comment: I was thinking more like Max's answer — in a declarative style, which is easy to recognise, read, and modify if needed.  I'd only resort to hard-coding it in an algorithm if that was really the most practical way (i.e. the information couldn't reasonably be put into a declarative form).

Comment: Thank you very much for the guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Map here:

```kotlin
data class LevelStage(val level: Int, val stage: Int)
data class Reward(val gold: Int, val xp: Int)

val levelToReward = mapOf(
    LevelStage(1, 1) to Reward(10, 10),
    LevelStage(2, 1) to Reward(20, 10),
)
val reward = levelToReward[LevelStage(chosenLevel, levelSelectScreen.stage)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in a json file like

```
{
  "0" : {
    "0" : {
     "goldReward": 50,
     "xpReward": 15
    },
    "1" : {
      "goldReward": 50,
     "xpReward": 15
    }
  },
  "1" : {
    "0" : {
      "goldReward": 50,
     "xpReward": 15
    },
    "1" : {
      "goldReward": 50,
     "xpReward": 15
    }
  }
   
}
```

and whenever you need the data you can fetch from json file

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but would this slow down my app compared to declaring it in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to serialize objects such as what you're likely suggesting.

For my game, I store configurable data [item boosts] in flat files instead of in code.